# Error: Cannot find module './commandsping.js'

Tags: discord

I created a folder and added my `ping.js` file, now I am receiving this error. This is probably the easiest thing but I am completely stuck is there something I am doing wrong? Here is a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjc20.jpg) of how my folder looks, code is below.

**Index.js file**

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();

['command', 'event'].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});


client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
    try {
      client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

you have made a mistake here. Change `./commands${file}` to `./commands/${file}`

```js
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the error stopped